# Download file from URL and upload to Drive without saving

Tags: node.js, request, google-drive-api

As the title says, I'm trying to get a file from an url and then upload it to Google Drive. The problem I'm getting is that my request returns a string with the binary data instead of the file.

As far, my code is:

```
function uploadFile(auth, url){
    var drive = google.drive('v2');
    request.get(url, function(err, res){
        if(err) {
            //Handles error.
        } else {
            drive.files.insert({
                auth: auth,
                uploadType: 'multipart',
                convert: true,
                media: {
                    body: res.body
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried to pipe the response to a buffer and then upload it to Drive but still got only the binary converted to a string. Does anyone has a hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res` is actually pipeable so you can pass it in i.e.

```
...,
media: {
    body: res,
}
```

I got to this conclusion by examining the [Google Node.js API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/cc9e138b0e3e507f585d9e38ba3f06ec4da58d1b/lib/apirequest.js#L24-L28), they have a function `isReadableStream`.

The code sample below should test this out to show you how res will be treated:

```
const request = require('request');
const stream  = require('stream');

request.get('https://www.drive.google.com', function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }

    console.log('is res streamable ? %s\nis res.body streamable ? %s\n',
        isReadableStream(res), isReadableStream(res.body));
});

function isReadableStream(obj) {
    return obj instanceof stream.Stream &&
       typeof obj._read === 'function' &&
       typeof obj._readableState === 'object';
}
```

And then inside:

```
// https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/cc9e138b0e3e507f585d9e38ba3f06ec4da58d1b/lib/apirequest.js#L183-L188
if (body) {
    body.pipe(req);
}
```

That's when they'll pipe the content of the response.

Hope this helps!